# Is it possible to write a Teleo-Reactive program in Java?

Tags: java

I am not sure if I have grasped the concept correctly. Teleo-Reactive programs are goal oriented programs. Do they have to be written in a language like Qu-Prolog or is it possible to write in Java?

Is it absolutely necessary to use a Logical Programming Language?

Thank you.

Comment: Generally, "any real-world general-purpose computer or computer language can approximately simulate the computational aspects of any other real-world general-purpose computer or computer language." See [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Comment: Theoretically you can solve all problems if you have time, if statements and recursion.